# VBA code for fetching numbers to multiple cells

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Hi I have difficulty putting numbers to multiple cells. 
I just want financial data to be put into cells in order, but I don't know 
why it doesn't work. (the code was given by another question post and I couldn't fully understand how the node hierarchy and with statement combined with for-loop work together)

I think my problem is in applying for loop in terms of Range().

I want to specify the stop( for ~~ to [this stop condition],

and the range of cells to receive the numbers but 
range("D" & i) = ~~ innerText
 doesn't work

```
Sub FetchFinanceInfo()
    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, i&

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    For Each post In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "From Operating Activities") > 0 Then
            With post.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For i = 1 To .Length - 1
                    Range("D4:D20") = post.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).innerText
                Next i
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FetchFinanceInfo()
    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, i&

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
    Dim td As Object, tds As Object
    Set tds = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("Bdbw(0px)! H(36px)")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")
    For Each td In tds
        ActiveSheet.Cells(4 + i, 4) = td.innerText
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Or adapting your example, which ignores the title cell of the row

```
Sub FetchFinanceInfo()
    Dim XMLReq As New XMLHTTP60, HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, i&

    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BABA/cash-flow?p=BABA", False
    XMLReq.send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    For Each post In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("span")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "From Operating Activities") > 0 Then
            With post.ParentNode.ParentNode.getElementsByTagName("td")
                For i = 1 To .Length - 1
                     ActiveSheet.Cells(3 + i, 4) = .item(i).innerText
                Next i
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```